# Have you ever had this error?

Tags: c#, odbc, connection-string, dbase

microsoft visual studio opens my table using dataset designer
but i cannot open my table using the same connectionstring.
my database is DBase IV.
and this is the connectionstring

> Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver 
>   (*.dbf)};collatingsequence=ASCII;dbq=d:\Data\88;deleted=0;driverid=277;fil=dBase
>   IV;maxbuffersize=2048;maxscanrows=8;pagetimeout=600;safetransactions=0;statistics=0;threads=3;uid=admin;usercommitsync=Yes

it is made by visual studio itself.
and this is my code

```
DataSet1TableAdapters.AN10TableAdapter _AN10TableAdapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.AN10TableAdapter();  
_AN10TableAdapter.Fill(D_Data.AN10);
```

and this is the error

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] Data source name not found
>   and no default driver specified

this real joke is killing me.
platform:vista x64
language:c#.net
.netframework vesion:3.5
worked on it:10 days

Comment: @unforgiven3 why did you downrate me? you want a picture of that?

Comment: where do you select the database name? is that implied by the `dbq`? and you never use the option `data source` I think this is what the error is saying

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I edited your question's title to make more sense. Don't assume the editor always is the downvoter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the issue is the 64-bitness of your machine. The driver is an unmanaged component and you probably have a single version of it (32-bit or 64-bit) installed on your machine. Since you cannot load 32-bit unmanaged components in a 64 bit process (and vice versa), it'll not work. Switch the target CPU setting of your project to x64 and x86 to force the assembly to run with the appropriate bitness and retry. It's likely to solve your problem.

Comment: i know that.
but why does visual studio browse everything of my table.
it can select, insert, etc ...

Comment: @behrooz: Visual Studio is a 32-bit app running in WOW64 mode. It can perfectly work with 32 bit ODBC drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the dBase data sources installed?

1. Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)
2. System DSN tab

(My OS is Windows XP but that's the idea.)